# Get unique keys and their unique values in a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am trying to get a list of all the unique keys in a JSON with a list of their unique values.

An example input looks like this:

```json
[{
    "key1": {"subkey1": "subvalue1", "subkey2": "subvalue2"},
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {"subkey3": "subvalue2"}
}, {
    "key4": "value4",
    "subkey1": "other_value",
    "key2": "value2"
}]
```

The expected output in this case would be:

```json
{
    "key1": [{"subkey1": "subvalue1", "subkey2": "subvalue2"}],
    "subkey1": ["subvalue1", "other_value"],
    "subkey2": ["subvalue2"],
    "key2": ["value2"],
    "key3": [{"subkey3": "subvalue2"}],
    "subkey3": ["subvalue2"]
    "key4": ["value4"]
}
```

I have tried setting up a recursive method to do this, but am not sure how to approach parsing the inner dictionary while also keeping it as a distinct value for that key. I also had trouble getting the unique inner keys then trying to get the values from those inner keys.

Here is how I started, but do not exactly know what to do from here:

```
@staticmethod
def get_distinct_keys_and_distinct_values_from_dict(list_of_dicts: [dict]) -> dict:
    print(DataParser.get_all_unique_keys(list_of_dicts))
    keys = DataParser.get_all_unique_keys(dictionary)
    # Not sure how to get to inner json and use correct key path in dictionaries

@staticmethod
def get_all_unique_keys(list_of_dicts: [dict]) -> set:
    keys = set()
    for dictionary in list_of_dicts:
        dict_keys = dictionary.keys()
        for key in dict_keys:
            keys.add(key)
        for key in keys:
            if key in dict_keys:
                value = dictionary[key]
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    keys = keys.union(DataParser.get_all_unique_keys([value]))
    return keys
```

Comment: Why are `subkey1` and `subkey2` included when `subkey3` is not?

Comment: Why is `subkey1` included twice (within `key1` and at top level) with different values?

Comment: I missed subkey3, that is my fault. subkey3 should be included too.

Comment: @Woodford I included subkey1 under key1 because I need to see what the object as a whole looks like under key1 too. Then subkey1 is also it's own key for a value so I need to see what values it could contain too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
def solution(data: list[dict]):
    result = dict()
    for d in data:
        collect_keys_and_values(d, result)
    return result

def collect_keys_and_values(data: dict, result: dict):
    for key, value in data.items():
        coll = result.setdefault(key, [])
        if value not in coll:
            coll.append(value)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            collect_keys_and_values(value, result)


def main():
    print(solution([{
    "key1": {"subkey1": "subvalue1", "subkey2": "subvalue2"},
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {"subkey3": "subvalue2"}
}, {
    "key4": "value4",
    "subkey1": "other_value",
    "key2": "value2"
}]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This solution worked on the complete JSON I had and appears to gather all distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

Since we want to traverse every list and dict, we call the recursive `get_unique_keys` while we walk them. While traversing a dictionary, we update the output dictionary by the key-value pairs. We use the if-else condition to keep only unique values.

```
def get_unique_keys(d, d_out={}):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for k in d:
            get_unique_keys(k, d_out)
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        for k,v in d.items():
            if k in d_out:
                if v not in d_out[k]:
                    d_out[k] += [v]
            else:
                d_out[k] = [v]
            get_unique_keys(v, d_out)
```

Output:

```
out = {}
get_unique_keys(lst, out)

>>> print(out)
{'subkey1': ['subvalue1', 'other_value'],
 'subkey2': ['subvalue2'],
 'key1': [{'subkey1': 'subvalue1', 'subkey2': 'subvalue2'}],
 'key2': ['value2'],
 'subkey3': ['subvalue2'],
 'key3': [{'subkey3': 'subvalue2'}],
 'key4': ['value4']}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for going back and looking at it again!

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(d_el, ans):
    try:
        for k in d_el.keys():
            if ans.get(k) and d_el[k] in ans[k]:
                continue
            ans.setdefault(k, []).append(d_el[k])
            foo(d_el[k], ans)
    except:
        pass

y = {}
for d_el in d:
    foo(d_el, y)
y
# {'key1': [{'subkey1': 'subvalue1', 'subkey2': 'subvalue2'}],
#  'subkey1': ['subvalue1', 'other_value'],
#  'subkey2': ['subvalue2'],
#  'key2': ['value2'],
#  'key3': [{'subkey3': 'subvalue2'}],
#  'subkey3': ['subvalue2'],
#  'key4': ['value4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can what you want by making use of the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) in conjunction with the [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class which are both in the standard library (assuming your data is JSON serializable). This is because the JSON decoder supports an `object_hook` argument which is a function it will call everytime it encounters a dictionary. `defaultdict` is used to create dictionaries-of-sets to make tracking unique value easy.

The basic idea is to specify a function via this argument that "watches" what is being decoded and keeps track of all the keys and values encountered while processing the data. The function first converts the data to JSON format and then reverses the process with this "watcher" function in place:

Here's what I mean:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json


inp = [{
           "key1": {"subkey1": "subvalue1", "subkey2": "subvalue2"},
           "key2": "value2",
           "key3": {"subkey3": "subvalue2"}
       }, {
           "key4": "value4",
           "subkey1": "other_value",
           "key2": "value2"
       }]


def  get_distinct_keys_and_distinct_values(data):
    results = defaultdict(set)

    def decode_dict(a_dict):  # "watcher" funtcion.
        for key, item in a_dict.items():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                for value in item.values():
                    results[key].add(value)
            else:
               results[key].add(item)
        return a_dict

    json_repr = json.dumps(data)  # Convert to JSON format.
    json.loads(json_repr, object_hook=decode_dict)  # Return value ignored.
    # Return results converted into a dictionary of lists.
    return {key: list(value) for key, value in results.items()}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(get_distinct_keys_and_distinct_values(inp), sort_dicts=False, compact=0)
```

Results:

```
{'subkey1': ['subvalue1', 'other_value'],
 'subkey2': ['subvalue2'],
 'subkey3': ['subvalue2'],
 'key1': ['subvalue1', 'subvalue2'],
 'key2': ['value2'],
 'key3': ['subvalue2'],
 'key4': ['value4']}
```

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer and I definitely learned a few things. Unfortunately, this does not quite do what I need. Ex. ```"key1": [{"subkey1": "subvalue1", "subkey2": "subvalue2"}]```. It looks like it only grabs the subvalues instead of including the entire inner object.

Comment: Doing that wouldn't allow sets to be use to eliminate duplicates because mutable items like dictionaries can be put into one. I'll think about how to get around that and update my answer if I come up with something.